# How to get the root path of Vue project at development mode?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, frontend

How to get the root path of the Vue project **from the browser** when running `npm run serve`

eg: the path `E:\myApp\`

Thanks in advance

I'v tried these:

1. `process.cwd()` but got `/`.
2. `require.resolve` but got webpack error `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`
3. `__dirname` and `path.resolve(__dirname)` return `/`

The Vue verison is `^3.2.37` and I use `Vue CLI`.

Comment: Which version of Vue? Using Vue CLI or Vite?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the Vue verison is `^3.2.37` and I use `Vue CLI`

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. You only have a project root when running the development server. Once your app is built, it's all just static files; they cannot reference the host filesystem

Comment: Also, why are you using Vue CLI with Vue3?

Comment: Emm, this is an old project, upgrade from Vue2, will try vite.

Comment: The reason I want to get this is that we need to create the Vue page file in to the frontend directory from the backend(the frontend and the backend both on the same computer). So we want to pass the path name(which we want to get it automatic) to the backend

Answer (score 0):

It's more a node problem, you can use:

```js
import path from "path";
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname);
console.log(absolutePath);
```

Comment: The question says, "from the browser"

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But the `__dirname` and `path.resolve(__dirname)` aways be `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always define a [computed environment variable](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code) in your `vue.config.js` file

```js
// vue.config.js
process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_PATH = __dirname;

module.exports = {};
```

Then in your app you can reference the environment variable

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ rootPath: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_PATH })
}
```

Note that this value will be fixed and never change once you build your app.